# Pass args to URL, but don't want it to show in the URL in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to pass extra options to django URL using reverse, but i dont want to show those arguments in URL

I tried the below mentioned code, but no luck, throwing **NoReverseMatch** Exception.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^foo-direct/', 'myapp.views.someview', {'wo_id': 1}, name='foo-direct'),
)
```

views.py

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('foo-direct', kwargs={'wo_id':2}))
```

Please suggest if i'm doing anything wrong.

**UPDATE**

How can i achieve without showing parameters in browser(url) ?

My view function accepts multiple parameters and i want to pass these multiple parameters , thus i dont want to show all the parameters in URL

Comment: Does this post help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515188/how-to-pass-extra-arguments-to-views-function-as-a-url-in-django

Comment: your views code is incorrect, your passing a variable which not exist in your url codes

Comment: Do you want to pass an id and at the same extra option? Or extra option only?

Comment: i want to pass only extra option, i dont want to show anything in url in browser.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing at the moment. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drop the kwargs parameter from your reverse function -

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('foo-direct')
```

UPDATE

You're not going to be able to use reverse with a dynamic `wo_id` unless you include the `wo_id` in the URL. The reverse function looks at all the url's in your url conf. It looks for a url with `args`, `kwargs`, and `name` matching the `args`, `kwargs` and `name` which you passed to `reverse`. When it finds a match it returns the corresponding function (a view).

I don't know why you don't want your wo_id in your url, so it's difficult to make suggestions, however, if you're trying to keep your url's descriptive then maybe you could look at using a slug field instead of an id.

Comment: my wo_id value will be dynamic, how can i pass wo_id dynamic value using reverse/

Comment: How can i achieve without showing parameters in browser(url) ?

My view function accepts multiple parameters and i want to pass these multiple parameters , thus i dont want to show all the parameters in URL

Comment: You really can't, the only way to pass dynamic variables to a view function is in the url.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't make any sense. There's no way a dynamic argument can be passed to the view without going through the URL. How would it get there? When the user actually went to that URL, how would Django know what parameter to use?